# Maxwell's distribution (find an amount of molecules)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, estimation

I am not familar with molecular physics much, so do not judge much please but,

How to find an amount of Hydrogen molecules in the volume of $1cm^3$ if it is know that  in normal conditions their velocity is between $399-401 m/s$

Comment: Questions like this are generally off-topic for this forum.  Take a look at  [this Meta post on asking "homework-like" questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).    You might get a better response at a more appropriate site.  [Here’s one to consider.](http://www.physicsforums.com), but there are others.    I will point out that there is not enough information in what you have written to answer the question.